# SOQL Query to Group By Month and Year

Tags: soql

Need help with a SOQL Query. We are trying to pull our highest sales records by month and user. Looking to see something like: "John Doe 100 Sales May 2014. Currently I am getting the calendar month, but not the year. Below is what I have currently, any suggestions are appreciated!

```
SELECT Count(Id), Sold_By__r.Name, calendar_month(Sold_By_Date__c) 
FROM Case 
WHERE Status = 'Sold' 
AND Sold_By__c !='005U0000000aL0BIAU' 
AND Sold_By__c !=''  
GROUP BY Sold_By__r.Name, calendar_month(Sold_By_Date__c) 
ORDER BY Count(Id) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use the CALENDAR_YEAR(Sold_By_Date__c) to pull out the year part of the data

```
SELECT Count(Id), Sold_By__r.Name, calendar_year(Sold_By_Date__c), calendar_month(Sold_By_Date__c) 
FROM Case 
WHERE Status = 'Sold' 
AND Sold_By__c !='005U0000000aL0BIAU' 
AND Sold_By__c !=''  
GROUP BY Sold_By__r.Name, calendar_year(Sold_By_Date__c), calendar_month(Sold_By_Date__c) 
ORDER BY Count(Id) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```