# Get number of records created per each of last 12 month in apex

Tags: query, map, createddate

I need to query Contacts which ***were created by the current user per each of the last 12 month*** and map them by month when they were created.
So I need Map<String,Integer> (***Map<Month,numberOfRecords>***).
I know that I can write some logic for accomplishing this.
However,
Maybe someone has already done something similar ?

Any help will be appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Not a complete duplicate I think, but you should find what you're looking for in this question; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47256/soql-query-to-group-by-month-and-year Basically; use `GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't get the expected results directly with groupBy query. You can follow the below approach.

1. Create a new field like "Calendar month" and update it with workflow. Then you can use the field in your query.

> CASE(MONTH(DateValue(Createddate)),
> 1, "January",
> 2, "February",
> 3, "March",
> 4, "April",
> 5, "May",
> 6, "June",
> 7, "July",
> 8, "August",
> 9, "September",
> 10, "October",
> 11, "November",
> 12, "December",
> "None")

2. Write a query like this and get records created in the last 12 months by the current user. Include the above custom field in the below query

   > SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) month,  COUNT(ID) Total  FROM
   > Opportunity  WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_MONTHS:12 and
   > createdbyid=UserInfo.getUserId() GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)
   > Order BY CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate)

Please let me know in case of any queries

Comment: Thank you. It is a good idea.
However I would like to accomplish this without creating any additional fields.

Comment: Yes, you can do that too by adding some logic to change CALENDAR_MONTH(CreatedDate) numeric values to month names.